# Performance is slow when replacing a string in a pandas dataframe using a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

The following code works but needs to run faster. The dict has ~25K keys and the dataframe is ~3M rows. Is there a way to produce the same results but with python code that will run faster? (without multiprocessing, processing would be 8x slower).

```
miscdict={" isn't ": ' is not '," aren't ":' are not '," wasn't ":' was not '," snevada ":' Sierra Nevada '}

df=pd.DataFrame({"q1":["beer is ok","beer isn't ok","beer wasn't available"," snevada is good"]})

def parse_text(data):
    for key, replacement in miscdict.items():
        data['q1'] = data['q1'].str.replace( key, replacement )
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1_1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
    split_dfs = np.array_split(df,8)
    pool_results = p.map(parse_text, split_dfs)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    parts = pd.concat(pool_results, axis=0)
    df = pd.concat([parts], axis=1)
    t2_1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("done"+ str(t2_1-t1_1))
```

Comment: Multiprocessing didn't help? Are you sure you did the multiprocessing correctly? This looks like an embarrassingly parallelizable problem. Maybe show how you did the palatalization?

Comment: I've updated the code to include the multiprocessing that I used. It is working (8x faster and system monitor shows all 8 cores fully utilized).

Answer (score 12):

I tested out a few of these. The suggestion of @A-Za-z is a major improvement, yet it might be possible to do it even faster.

**edit**: I've rerun the tests where I precomputed the replacement dict and the dataframe (and the precompiled regex). The new timings are:

- Original: 11.71 seconds
- @A-Za-z: 4.72 seconds, a 60% improvement.
- @piRSquared: 4.95 seconds, a 58% improvement.
- Precompiled: 2.81 seconds, a 76% improvement.

The original results where data generation and regex compiling were included in the timings:

> "Testing your code I got 15 seconds, @A-Za-z's code gave 8-9 seconds, and my own solution moved it down to 6 seconds. It uses precompiled regex. See the end of this answer."

---

Imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import timeit
```

---

Your original code:

```
miscdict = {" isn't ": ' is not '," aren't ":' are not '," wasn't ":' was not '," snevada ":' Sierra Nevada '}
data=pd.DataFrame({"q1":["beer is ok","beer isn't ok","beer wasn't available"," snevada is good"]})
def org(printout=False):
    def parse_text(data):
        for key, replacement in miscdict.items():
            data['q1'] = data['q1'].str.replace( key, replacement )
        return data
    data2 = parse_text(data)
    if printout:
        print(data2)
org(printout=True)
print(timeit.timeit(org, number=10000))
```

This used 11.7 seconds:

```
                       q1
0              beer is ok
1          beer is not ok
2  beer was not available
3   Sierra Nevada is good
11.71043858179268
```

---

User @A-Za-z's code:

```
miscdict = {" isn't ": ' is not '," aren't ":' are not '," wasn't ":' was not '," snevada ":' Sierra Nevada '}
data=pd.DataFrame({"q1":["beer is ok","beer isn't ok","beer wasn't available"," snevada is good"]})
def alt1(printout=False):
    data['q1'].replace(miscdict, regex = True, inplace = True)
    if printout:
        print(data)
alt1(printout=True)
print(timeit.timeit(alt1, number=10000))
```

This used 4.7 seconds:

```
                       q1
0              beer is ok
1          beer is not ok
2  beer was not available
3   Sierra Nevada is good
4.721581550644499
```

---

User @piRSquared's code:

```
miscdict = {" isn't ": ' is not '," aren't ":' are not '," wasn't ":' was not '," snevada ":' Sierra Nevada '}
data=pd.DataFrame({"q1":["beer is ok","beer isn't ok","beer wasn't available"," snevada is good"]})
def alt2(printout=False):
    # regex = True is added later because it doesn't work without it.
    data = data.replace(miscdict, regex = True)
    if printout:
        print(data)
alt2(printout=True)
print(timeit.timeit(alt2, number=10000))
```

This used 5.0 seconds:

```
                       q1
0              beer is ok
1          beer is not ok
2  beer was not available
3   Sierra Nevada is good
4.951810616074919
```

---

```
miscdict = {" isn't ": ' is not '," aren't ":' are not '," wasn't ":' was not '," snevada ":' Sierra Nevada '}
miscdict_comp = {re.compile(k): v for k, v in miscdict.items()}
data=pd.DataFrame({"q1":["beer is ok","beer isn't ok","beer wasn't available"," snevada is good"]})
def alt3(printout=False):
    def parse_text(text):
        for pattern, replacement in miscdict_comp.items():
            text = pattern.sub(replacement, text)
        return text
    data["q1"] = data["q1"].apply(parse_text)
    if printout:
        print(data)
alt3(printout=True)
print(timeit.timeit(alt3, number=10000))
```

This used 2.8 seconds:

```
                       q1
0              beer is ok
1          beer is not ok
2  beer was not available
3   Sierra Nevada is good
2.810334940701157
```

The idea is to precompile the pattern you're looking to change.

I got the idea from here: https://jerel.co/blog/2011/12/using-python-for-super-fast-regex-search-and-replace

Comment: Wow! Even faster. You guys were a huge help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Outstanding answer. Good work with the research. Plus one from me.

Comment: Andre' -> you've helped me go from a situation where the job wouldn't finish to where now it only takes 2 hours to complete. When working with a large text corpus, Precompiled regex appears to be a necessary task.

Comment: idea of pre-compiling patterns is really helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the loop here, df.replace does the job along with regex = True and it cuts the time by more than half.

```
df['q1'].replace(miscdict, regex = True, inplace = True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 ms per loop
```

gets you

```
        q1
0   beer is ok
1   beer is not ok
2   beer was not available
3   Sierra Nevada is good
```

Comparing this with the current solution

```
for key, replacement in miscdict.items(): df['q1'] = df['q1'].str.replace( key, replacement )
100 loops, best of 3: 2.35 ms per loop
```

Comment: Much faster! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

WOW!  We've reinvented the wheel and engineered some snazzy spokes and spikes and...

... Just do this

```
df.replace(miscdict)

                       q1
0              beer is ok
1          beer is not ok
2  beer was not available
3   Sierra Nevada is good
```

Unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Could be a problem with the version but it doesn't give the desired result to me without regex=True

Comment: The question was not about elegance, it specifically asked for speed.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen thanks for that, did you check the speed?  Over 400,000 rows it provides 10 fold improvement over OPs parser. I'm not as capable of posting as thorough an answer as usual but I thought an answer that simplifies as well as improved was important to get out there. I'm sorry you don't find this answer useful. I appreciate the input and the down vote.

Comment: @piRSquared Your contribution is naturally welcomed, however, IMO we should strive for our communication on SO to be as professional and non-combative as possible. I found your answer to be on the demeaning side. That said, I do feel the downvote was overzealous on my part. If you do a slight edit of your comment, any edit, I'll be allowed to revert it.

Comment: I tested the pure `df.replace(miscdict)` version. Initially I thought it worked, but it seems I was wrong. I think @A-Za-z is right and you actually need to set `regex = True` for it to work. What version of pandas did you use if it worked on your end?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6, pandas version 0.19.2. This command works: data['q1'].replace(miscdict, regex = True, inplace = True). This command does not work: data['q1']=data['q1'].replace(miscdict, regex = True, inplace = True). A-Za-z helped me see my error.

Answer (score 1):

Using the precompiled miscdict with the example from Vaishali was about 10x faster in my case with other data than shown below:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({"q1":["beer is ok","beer isn't ok","beer wasn't available"," snevada is good"]})

miscdict = {" isn't ": ' is not '," aren't ":' are not '," wasn't ":' was not '," snevada ":' Sierra Nevada '}
miscdict_comp = {re.compile(k): v for k, v in miscdict.items()}

data['q1'].replace(miscdict_comp, regex = True, inplace = True)
```